# Methods in Dice Program return 0

Tags: java

I've just started programming in Java and I've encountered a problem that I just can't seem to figure out.

My program is meant to roll a die with (n) sides, where (n) is specified by the user. The program will then print the result of the roll as an integer, the face value of the roll as an integer (this seems to be the same as the result of the roll), and the result of the roll as a string. The last two methods (face value and string) are separate methods from the die roll, but are still required.

My problem is that although the code compiles, the methods getFaceValue() and toString() return both return zero. My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Die {

  private int z;
  private String faceName;

//sets (and returns) the face value to a uniform random number between 1 and the number of faces.
public int roll() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sides = keyboard.nextInt();
    double x = Math.random();
    double y = (x * sides) + 1;
    z = (int)y;
    return z;
}

//returns the current face value of the die.
public int getFaceValue() {
    int face = z;
    return face;
}

//returns the string representation of the face value.
public String toString() {
    faceName = Integer.toString(z);
    return faceName;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    System.out.println("How many sides will the die have?");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Roll: " + new Die().roll());
    System.out.println("Face: " + new Die().getFaceValue());
    System.out.println("String: " + new Die().toString());
}
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: You don't use `new` die for each roll, do you? :) Instanciate `Die` once, reuse to roll() and getFaceValue(). It may also worth looking at `Random#nextInt()` with seed value as number of faces in your die.

Comment: Although your problem is solved, just wanted to point out this thing :- "Why are you declaring a local variable `face` in `getFaceValue()`, just to return it".. You are just creating a `copy` of your instance variable `z` for no good..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I see is that fact that you're creating three instance of your Die class, meaning that any values genereted will not effect the others....

```
System.out.println("Roll: " + new Die().roll());
System.out.println("Face: " + new Die().getFaceValue());
System.out.println("String: " + new Die().toString());
```

Should read

```
Die die = new Die();
System.out.println("Roll: " + die.roll());
System.out.println("Face: " + die.getFaceValue());
System.out.println("String: " + die.toString());
```

I'd also move the prompt `System.out.println("How many sides will the die have?")` to the `roll` method, seen as that's where you're actually asking the question, but that's just me

Comment: That did it. The program now compiles and the values returned by getFaceValue() and toString() match up with roll(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `new Die()`, you are creating a new die that is independent of the last one. So you are making a die and then rolling it, then making another die and looking at the value. Since you have not rolled it yet, it still has the default value of `0`, so that is what is output. You want to have the same die that you roll and then look at, like so:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Die die = new Die();
    System.out.println("How many sides will the die have?");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Roll: " + die.roll());
    System.out.println("Face: " + die.getFaceValue());
    System.out.println("String: " + die.toString());
}
```

This will create a die, and then roll it and look at its value. It will show the same value for all three method calls.