# (Homework) Dice Program, cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I've encountered yet another error with my dice program.

In this program I have three methods, roll() to roll the die and return a value between 1 and a number specified by the user, getFaceValue(), to return the value of the die roll as an int, and toString(), to return the die roll as a string.

The answer to my previous question about my program enabled me to get the program working, but it was not structured as the professor wanted, so I've had to rework it. I now know that none of my methods/variables can be static, and I can only take user input in the main part of the program.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Die.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
double y = (x * sides) + 1;

symbol: variable sides
location: class Die
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Die {
    //private int sides;
    private int z;
    private String faceName;

    //sets (and returns) the face value to a uniform random number between 1 and the number of faces.
    public int roll() {
        double x = Math.random();
        double y = (x * sides) + 1;
        z = (int)y;
        return z;
    }

    //returns the current face value of the die.
    public int getFaceValue() {
        int face = z;
        return face;
    }

    //returns the string representation of the face value.
    public String toString() {
        faceName = Integer.toString(z);
        return faceName;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int sides;
        System.out.println("How many sides will the die have?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        sides = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" ");
        Die die = new Die();
        System.out.println("Roll: " + die.roll());
        System.out.println("Face: " + die.getFaceValue());
        System.out.println("String: " + die.toString());
    }
}
```

Originally, I had the variable sides as a private int (you can see it commented out in my program), but this produced a static reference error.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

The previous question was: [Methods in Dice Program return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594572/methods-in-dice-program-return-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance variable for `sides` and pass it to the die via a constructor.  This would require you to uncomment your `private int sides` variable.

Example Die constructor:

```
public Die(int sides) {
    this.sides = sides;
}
```

With a constructor like this, you can instantiate your Die with the number of sides you read as input.

```
sides = keyboard.nextInt();
Die die = new Die(sides);
```

Now, your die's `sides` field is set to whatever the user entered, and the die's methods use that value accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Also, I apologize for not linking to the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `sides` inside the scope of `public int roll() {`

Creating a variable inside main narrows it's scope to only inside main- you can't access outside of that unless you pass it in as a variable (which will be passed by value) or make it a class variable (a field).

As a die, you want to make it a field on the actual class. So define sides in the top of the class:

```
public class Die {
  int sides;
```

and assign it in your constructor:

```
public Die(int s) {
  sides = s;
}
```

then when you call `roll`, your sides variable will be available.

Comment: Yes that will work, but think about it like a true-to-life model.  If you have a dice, does it have a changeable number of sides that you can swap whenever you roll it? Nope.

Comment: @Vulcan You're right- I didn't really take that into account the first time I wrote the answer. Updated to reflect better class integration.

Answer (score 0):

your variable sides is undefined
you could pass if by value like so

```
public int roll(int sides) {
    .....
    double y = (x * sides) + 1;
    .....
}
```

Comment: Yes that will work, but think about it like a true-to-life model. If you have a dice, does it have a changeable number of sides that you can swap whenever you roll it? Nope.

Comment: @Vulcan, I often treat my d6 as a d2, d3, or d6. :p

Comment: @Vulcan good point there, a dice constructor would be more appropriate, so as to set the sides only once.. In gambling a changing dice = getting kicked out with a bonus of being beat up x)

Comment: @MimiEAM As awesome as a changing dice would be.. xD Anyway I think it's good for the OP's learning experience that your answer was posted though as an example of something that will work (and with less work than an answer such as mine), but does not model a real life situation in the way one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

pass **sides** as an argument to the roll method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Die {
//private int sides;  
private int z;
private String faceName;

//sets (and returns) the face value to a uniform random number between 1 and the number of faces.
public int roll(int sides) {
    double x = Math.random();
    double y = (x * sides) + 1;
    z = (int)y;
    return z;
}


public static void main(String [] args) {
        int sides;
        System.out.println("How many sides will the die have?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        sides = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" ");
        Die die = new Die();
        System.out.println("Roll: " + die.roll(sides)); // pass it as an argument to roll
        System.out.println("Face: " + die.getFaceValue());
        System.out.println("String: " + die.toString());
    }

    }
```

Comment: Yes that will fix the compilation error, but OP is asking for a solution that works as his program did in his other question (which he unfortunately did not link in this question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are getting is that `sides` is local to the `main()` method, and is not passed in any way to the `roll()` method. When the compiler is compiling `roll()`, it sees `double y = (x * sides) + 1;` and has no idea what `sides` refers to - hence the error.

There are two ways you can accomplish this, but you should find a way to pass the inputs you collect from the user in `main()` to your `Die` class. One way to do this would be in the constructor of the Die class:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int sides = keyboard.nextInt();
    ...
    Die die = new Die(sides);
```

You then change the `Die` class to have a constructor that accepts an `int` and keeps track of it in a *member field* called `sides` (although the names of the variables in the `main()` method and the `Die` class do not need to actually be the same, this is just a convenience).

```
public class Die {
    private int sides;

    public Die(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    public int roll() {
        ...
        double y = (x * this.sides) + 1;
```