# Custom Dice Generator

Tags: java

Okay so this is for homework. I don't want a complete answer, just someone to help nudge me in the right direction. I am fairly new to Java, so please take it easy :P Okay so my professor is having us do a Dice simulation program with OOP. This is just one portion of the entire problem, but it's the part I'm stuck on, so if you need more I can provide more. But the instructions say:Make a Roll function that will simulate rolling each die, and return the total
This function should only allow values between the appropriate range (i.e. if each die only has 4 faces, only numbers 1 - 4 should be allowed).
What I have so far for this particular function is this:

```
public double Roll()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
    double total = Math.random()*numFaces + 1;
    }
    return total;
```

I don't know where to go from here, and I don't know what really to do. This is my first programming class and it's way over my head :P So like I said, if I could just get pointed in the right direction (using dummy talk, cause I'm still having a hard time grasping this whole thing) that would be awesome. And I can provide more of the actual problem if need be.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610008/homework-dice-program-cannot-find-symbol?rq=1) your Homework? :P

Comment: @RahilArora If only all students would check stack overflow first for their homework. HAHA!

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed you used double , replace double with int or short. Look at the following tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Your also not so hot with naming conventions. Read this.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

You don't need to roll for each face, only for each dice. Do this.

Please note, for this you could use shorts as well.

```
public int roll() {
    return new Random().nextInt(6) + 1; // Returns number between 1 and 6
}
```

If you want to roll multiple dice you could do this.

```
public int roll(int amount) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        total += new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `total` inside the `for` loop, which makes it invisible outside it. Also, you're overwriting it (=) instead of adding to it (+=) on each die throw.

```
public double Roll()
{
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        total += Math.random()*numFaces + 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

I would also recommend to follow Java style and rename the method `roll` (methods start with a lowercase letter). The return type also strikes me as odd, I would probably use `int` in a similar situation.

Comment: Although correct, the OP said he only wanted a push in the right direction = **not a complete solution**

Comment: That's about as short of a push I consider to be even feasible.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Please tell me how to do that. I would really like to know.

Comment: @Zeveso Only give a push in the right direction? Easy, read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class named `Die` to represent a die. This fits with OOP as 'die' would be one of your nouns. Now think of what configuration and behavior a `Die` might have. You may wish to have a `Die` have a configurable number of faces, but default to 6 if it isn't specified. You also want to be able to roll a die. Lets see what we have so far. ***Implementation left up to the reader.***

```
public class Die {

    public Die(){
        this(6);
    }

    public Die(int faces){
        //TODO: Write a constructor that takes number faces as an argument.
    }


    public int roll(){
        //TODO: Implement a roll for this die, considering the number of faces.
    }

}
```

Ok, so you have the beginning of a Die class. Now you might think, wouldn't it be cool if I could group die together as `Dice` (a set of dice if you will).

```
public class Dice { 

    public Dice(Die... dice){
        //TODO: Implement constructor that takes an array of die objects.
    }

    public int roll(){
        //TODO: Roll all the dice, sum and return the result.
    }
}
```

Next you might think, man wouldn't it be sweet if I could treat `Dice` and a single `Die` as a single type, I mean they both can be rolled. Let us create an interface called `Rollable` that specified the roll behavior and have both `Dice` and `Die` implement it.

```
public interface Rollable {

    int roll();

}
```

Then go back and change the class declarations to be.

```
public class Die implements Rollable
```

and

```
public class Dice implements Rollable
```

Now code that needs to roll things only needs to worry about `Rollable` instead of `Die` or `Dice`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare the total outside the for-loop. Then initialize it to zero.

Then, inside the for-loop. Increase the variable.

If `numFaces` should be able to be different for each die, you will need to get the value for it inside the for-loop, on each iteration.

Also, you should ask yourself: Which possible values do I want for the `total` variable? Should it be `int` or `double`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define total outside the for loop and then do total+=… inside the loop